# calling something which doesn't exist in conditions

Tags: if-statement, conditional-statements, statements

Is this correct to call something which actually doesn't exist in a condintion.

I'm using if statements to check two conditions, but for the first iteration, one of the called arguments doesn't exist. However the program works fine, but is it still correct ?

the program takes the fullname and convert the first initials to Uppercase and print them.

```
int main(void) {
    string fullname = GetString();
    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(fullname); i < n; i++) {
        if (fullname[i] != ' ' && fullname[i-1] == ' ' ) {
            printf("%c", toupper(fullname[i]));
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What programming language is this?

Comment: If you expect that sometimes something doesn't exist then check first for Null and continue only if this is not null

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer: *It's not correct although it runs well sometimes.***

For `&&`, if `fullname[i] != ' '` is false, compile will not check `fullname[i-1] == ' '` as `false && whatever` will be always false. That's why it will run correctly *sometimes*. It's so called [**Short-circuit evaluation**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

But, you should avoid to write such code in practice. It will potentially cause errors when `fullname[i] != ' '` is true. It will then evaluate `fullname[i-1] == ' '`, i.e. `fullname[-1]`, which will trigger ***`Access Violation at Address Error`***. Try to change the `if`-statement to the following:

```
if (fullname[i]!=' ' && i>0 && fullname[i-1]==' ') { // make it always right
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not correct, and could lead to a program crash.  For your above code, if full name was, say "Fred", then you would be checking full name [-1].  At best, this would contain an undefined value - but if full name happened to be at the boundary of your programs allocated memory, you would be accessing outside the allowable range - hence program crash.

Only ever access what you know has been set.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just try

```
for (int i = 1, n = strlen(fullname); i < n; i++) {
```

Starting at an offset of 1 unless the string length is 1?